# TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: last_hidden_state

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have been trying to train a model for sentence similarity using BERT and I am encountering this error. I did search all over and was unable to find a solution, can someone help me with this? Attaching code for your reference.

```
 # Create the model under a distribution strategy scope.
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
    # Encoded token ids from BERT tokenizer.
    input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_ids"
    )
    # Attention masks indicates to the model which tokens should be attended to.
    attention_masks = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="attention_masks"
    )
    # Token type ids are binary masks identifying different sequences in the model.
    token_type_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="token_type_ids"
    )
    # Loading pretrained BERT model.
    bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
    # Freeze the BERT model to reuse the pretrained features without modifying them.
    bert_model.trainable = False

    sequence_output, pooled_output = bert_model(
        input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks, token_type_ids=token_type_ids
    )
    # Add trainable layers on top of frozen layers to adapt the pretrained features on the new data.
    bi_lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)
    )(sequence_output)
    # Applying hybrid pooling approach to bi_lstm sequence output.
    avg_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(bi_lstm)
    max_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(bi_lstm)
    concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])
    dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(concat)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(dropout)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids], outputs=output
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["acc"],
    )


print(f"Strategy: {strategy}")
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly access the `last_hidden_state` property of the output from the Bert model:

```py
with strategy.scope():
    # Encoded token ids from BERT tokenizer.
    input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_ids"
    )
    # Attention masks indicates to the model which tokens should be attended to.
    attention_masks = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="attention_masks"
    )
    # Token type ids are binary masks identifying different sequences in the model.
    token_type_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(
        shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="token_type_ids"
    )
    # Loading pretrained BERT model.
    bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
    # Freeze the BERT model to reuse the pretrained features without modifying them.
    bert_model.trainable = False

    output = bert_model(
        input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)

    bi_lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)
    )(output['last_hidden_state'])
    # Applying hybrid pooling approach to bi_lstm sequence output.
    avg_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(bi_lstm)
    max_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(bi_lstm)
    concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])
    dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(concat)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(dropout)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids], outputs=output
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["acc"],
    )

print(f"Strategy: {strategy}")
model.summary()
```

If you want to use all hidden states instead of just the last one, then try something like the following. Note that you must set the `output_hidden_states` parameter of the BertConfig to `True` and pass this configuration to the Bert model. The output is a list of 13 hidden states, which is why they are concatenated before being passed to the `LSTM` layer.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig
import transformers

# Loading pretrained BERT model.
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", output_hidden_states=True)
bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", config = config)
# Freeze the BERT model to reuse the pretrained features without modifying them.
bert_model.trainable = False

output = bert_model(
    input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)

all_hidden_states = tf.concat(output['hidden_states'], axis=1)
bi_lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)
)(all_hidden_states)
```